# Calling Protected Function From Derived Friend Function

Tags: c++, oop, friend, derived-class

I have a base class, `Animal`, and a derived class, `Lion`. `Animal` has a protected function called `eat()`. I would like to call `eat()` from a friend function defined in `Lion`, but when it won't compile:

```
error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
```

Why can't I call a protected function from a friend of `Lion`? I have work-arounds, but I can't figure out why a friend wouldn't be able to call `eat()`. It doesn't seem to matter if I use `Animal::eat` or `Lion::eat`, I get the same error. Thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
    Animal(int m) : mass(m){}
    int getMass() const { return mass; }
protected:
    int mass;
    void eat(const Animal& lhs, const Animal& rhs, Animal *result){
        result->mass = lhs.getMass() + rhs.getMass();
    }
};

class Gazelle : public Animal{
public:
    Gazelle(int m) : Animal(m){}
};

class Lion : public Animal{
public:
    Lion(int m) : Animal(m){}

    friend Lion feed(const Lion &lhs, const Gazelle &rhs){
        Lion hungry(0);
        eat(lhs, rhs, &hungry);
        return hungry;
    }
};

int main(void){
    Lion leo(5);
    Gazelle greg(1);

    Lion fullLeo = feed(leo, greg);
    cout << "Full Leo has mass " << fullLeo.getMass() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `eat()` is not declared static...

Comment: You'll need any `Animal` instance (e.g. a `Lion`) to call it: `leo.eat(lhs, rhs, &hungry);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `friend` function is a non member function which has access to private members of a class. But you still have to provide the object details for accessing data members.

The usage of `eat` function must be similar to `object_name.eat()` in the `feed` function.

Comment: Ah yes - True. Even accessing private members must be done from an object, e.g. `lhs.mass`